# Pandas: General Data Imputation Based on Column Dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataset with ~80 columns, many of which contain NaN.  I definitely don't want to manually inspect `dtype` for each column and impute based on that.

So I wrote a function to impute a column's missing values based on its `dtype`:

```
def impute_df(df, col):
    # if col is float, impute mean
    if df[col].dtype == "int64":
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(), inplace=True)
    else:
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mode()[0], inplace=True)
```

But to use this, I'd have to loop over all columns in my DataFrame, something like:

```
for col in train_df.columns:
    impute_df(train_df, col)
```

And I know looping in Pandas is generally slow.  Is there a better way of going about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for numeric and non numeric columns and then apply fillna for filtered columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,np.nan,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':['a','a','b','b','b',np.nan]})

print (df)

   A    B    C  D  E    F
0  a  NaN  7.0  1  5    a
1  b  5.0  8.0  3  3    a
2  c  4.0  NaN  5  6    b
3  d  5.0  4.0  7  9    b
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2    b
5  f  4.0  3.0  0  4  NaN

cols1 = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns
cols2 = df.select_dtypes(exclude = [np.number]).columns
df[cols1] = df[cols1].fillna(df[cols1].mean())
df[cols2] = df[cols2].fillna(df[cols2].mode().iloc[0])
print (df)
   A    B    C  D  E  F
0  a  4.6  7.0  1  5  a
1  b  5.0  8.0  3  3  a
2  c  4.0  4.8  5  6  b
3  d  5.0  4.0  7  9  b
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2  b
5  f  4.0  3.0  0  4  b
```

Comment: Thanks.  What are `col1` and `col2` in your example?  I see `cols1` and `cols2` defined...

Comment: oops, it is columns ;)

Comment: Oh I meant on lines 3 and 4 of your function body, within `fillna` you reference `df[col1]` and 'df[col2]'.  What're `col1` and `col2` here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need a function here,

for example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,np.nan,3,4],'A_1':[1,np.nan,3,4],'B':['A','A',np.nan,'B']})

v=df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).columns
t=~df.columns.isin(v)
df.loc[:,v]=df.loc[:,v].fillna(df.loc[:,v].mean().to_dict())

df.loc[:,t]=df.loc[:,t].fillna(df.loc[:,t].mode().iloc[0].to_dict())


df
Out[1440]: 
          A       A_1  B
0  1.000000  1.000000  A
1  2.666667  2.666667  A
2  3.000000  3.000000  A
3  4.000000  4.000000  B
```